# Is it possible to configure storm in windows operating system? If so please tell us the procedure

Tags: apache-storm

To process big data storm tool can be used. We got the information about storm. But we dont know whether it can be configured in windows operating system. So if anyone could answer it will be very useful to us

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Checkout this article and see whether it can help you: [Running Apache Storm on Windows](http://ptgoetz.github.io/blog/2013/12/18/running-apache-storm-on-windows/).

Comment: Thanks we will follow this steps and let us inform you.

Comment: we did all the steps mentioned in the url.what will be the next step to implement out project?

Comment: We need more information about working of storm can you send any article to understand "how to work with storm"

Comment: We completed all the steps mentioned in the above url.compiled topology mentioned int he url.but we didn't get any output of the topology.please help us to know about how to give input to the topology and how get output of the topology.Thank you chiron